# Trying to build Expression for Table field to sort text dates, some with missing elements

Tags: date, ms-access-2013

Hi I am a newbie and have a problem I have been trying to solve for weeks. I have a table imported from excel with dates in text format (because dates go back to 1700s) Most are in the format "mmmyyyy", so it is relatively easy to add "1" to the date, convert to date format, and sort in correct date order. The problem I have is that some of the dates in the table are simply "yyyy", and some are empty. I cannot find an expression that works to convert these last two to eg 1 Jan yyyy and 1 Jan 1000 within the same expression. Is this possible, or would I need to do this in two queries? Sorry if this question is very basic - I cannot find an answer anywhere.
TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
Public Function ConvertDate(Byval Expression As Variant) As Date

    Dim Result As Date

    If IsNull(Expression) Then
        Result = DateSerial(1000, 1, 1)
    ElseIf Len(Expression) = 4 Then
        Result = DateSerial(Expression, 1, 1)
    Else
        Result = DateValue(Right(Expression, 4) & "/" & Left(Expression, 3) & "/1")
    End If

    ConvertDate = Result

End Function
```